# Invalid order of first low priority operation in NSOperationQueue

Tags: ios, swift, nsoperationqueue

Really wondering, why the position of the first operation isn't changed after changing the suspended state to `false`.

```swift
    let operationQueue = OperationQueue.main

    let operation1 = BlockOperation { print("1") }
    operation1.queuePriority = .low

    let operation2 = BlockOperation { print("2") }
    operation2.queuePriority = .normal

    let operation3 = BlockOperation { print("3") }
    operation3.queuePriority = .high

    let operation4 = BlockOperation { print("4") }
    operation4.queuePriority = .veryHigh

    operationQueue.isSuspended = true
    operationQueue.addOperation(operation1)
    operationQueue.addOperation(operation2)
    operationQueue.addOperation(operation3)
    operationQueue.addOperation(operation4)
    operationQueue.isSuspended = false
```

Print output:

```swift
1
4
3
2
```

Expected print output:

```swift
4
3
2
1
```

**UPD**
Noticed this behavior only for `OperationQueue.main`. For custom `OperationQueue()` with `maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1` works as expected.

Comment: See notes in https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operation/1411204-queuepriority regarding caveat about using `queuePriority` to manage operation order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot suspend `.main`. That's a system queue.

This is more explicitly explained in the documentation for the underlying [`DispatchQueue.main`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqueue):

> As with the global concurrent queues, calls to suspend(), resume(), dispatch_set_context(*:*:), and the like have no effect when used on the queue in this property.

When you schedule the first task, the queue is empty, and it's the highest priority, so it's immediately scheduled. When there are pending tasks in the queue, they get ordered by priority, though this isn't promised. If you need an order, you use dependencies, not priorities. Priorities are a hint, and in my experience, should generally be avoided unless you have a very specialized problem.

In the case of your custom queue, it really is suspended, so the first task doesn't get scheduled as soon as you enqueue it.

Comment: Thanks! But why I don't see the following output: [1, 2, 3, 4] then? The 2-4 operations are sorted in proper priority positions though.

Comment: Because when 1 was added to the main queue, there was nothing else there (and the main queue cannot be suspended), so it might just start. But 2-4 will tend to reflect their priority (though it is not guaranteed, as Rob Napier said). But as he said, don’t use priority if you must have them run in a particular order; use dependencies.